# Cannot connect to Discord gateway from Cloudflare Workers

Tags: websocket, discord, cloudflare-workers

I have a Discord bot running on cloudflare workers which I want to update the presence of, using the gateway. The following snippet works in my browser console but not in workers:

```js
export function setPresence(token: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const activities = [{
            name: `you`,
            type: 3
        }];
        const socket = new WebSocket("wss://gateway.discord.gg/?v=10&encoding=json");

        function send(op, d) {
            return socket.send(JSON.stringify({ op, d }));
        }

        socket.addEventListener("error", e => console.error(e) || reject(e));
        socket.addEventListener("open", _ => console.log("websocket open"));
        socket.addEventListener("close", _ => console.log("websocket closed") || resolve());
        socket.addEventListener("message", event => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
            const { op, d } = data;
            console.log({ data });

            switch (op) {
                case 1: // Heartbeat
                case 10: { // Hello
                    send(1, null);
                    break;
                };
                case 11: { // Heartbeat ACK
                    send(2, {
                        token,
                        properties: {
                            os: "linux",
                            browser: "cloudflare workers",
                            device: "cloudflare workers"
                        },
                        intents: 0
                    });
                    break;
                }
                case 0: { // Ready
                    console.log("websocket ready");
                    send(3, {
                        activities: [activities[Math.floor(activities.length * Math.random())]],
                        status: "online",
                        since: 91879201,
                        afk: false
                    });
                    setTimeout(_ => socket.close(), 10000);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Browser screenshot]

When I run it in workers with `wrangler dev --remote` I get no `websocket open` log, just an error event and a `websocket closed`

[image]

I have tried using `fetch("https://gateway.discord.gg/?v=10&encoding=json")` and accessing the `webSocket` property of the response but it is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately an intentional block by Discord who have prevented Cloudflare Workers from connecting to their Gateway.

> Yeah - due to a layered security approach, we've intentionally prevented CF workers from connecting to our Gateway sockets. [1](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/6145)

You can still use Interactions, which are outgoing webhooks to your Worker, as demonstrated at https://discord.com/developers/docs/tutorials/hosting-on-cloudflare-workers.